# Multiply two numbers whose range is 10^18

Tags: algorithm, math, modulo

There is a variable `first_variable` which is always a mod of some number, `mod_value`.
In every step `first_variable` is multiplied with some number `second_variable`.

And the range of all three variables is from `1` to `10^18`.

For that I build a formula,

```
first_variable = ((first_variable%mod_value)*(second_variable%mod_value))%mod_value
```

But this gives a wrong answer,

For example,   If `first_variable and second_variable` is `(10^18)-1` and `mod_value = 10^18`

Please suggest me method, so that `first_variable` will always give right answer.

Comment: What is the programming language you used? There must be an overflow. 
If you are using 64 bit for smaller length fixed size variables (eg, long in java (64 bit), int in java (32 bit), this kind of multiplication overflows if the result is larger than the maximum number that data type can hold.

Comment: I am using C++. IS it possible to solve by using `unsigned long long or long long` ?

Comment: Unlike your platform is something very exotic, `long long` won't help. It's only 64 bits on Windows (Visual Studio, etc.) and Unix. OTOH, GCC has __int128 type implemented in its own library. You can try it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I calculate (A\*B)%C for A,B,C <= 10^18, in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912109/how-can-i-calculate-abc-for-a-b-c-1018-in-c)

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912109/how-can-i-calculate-abc-for-a-b-c-1018-in-c/20912380

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using a runtime where arithmetic is implemented using 64-bit integers. You can check this using multipliers like 2^32: if their product is 0, my guess is true. In that case, you should switch to an arbitrary long arithmetic implementation, or at least one that is much longer than the current one. E.g. Python supports integers up to 2^1016 (256^127), same for Erlang.

I've seen in comments you use C++. If so, look for GMP library and analogs. Or, if 128 bits is enough, modern GCC support it through own library.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically overflows, so you should either use different value for mod_value (up to 10^9) or limit the range for first value and second value.

Answer (score 0):

Your number is `O(10^36)` which is `O(2^108)` which cannot fit in any primitive data type in languages like java or C++. Use BigInt in C++ or Java or use numpy in python to get over it.

Comment: Big-Oh notation isn't suitable for this. O() takes functions as parameters, and if `10^36` were to stand for `f(n) = 10^36` the number would also be in O(-1) or O(0). It just doesn't make sense to use it for this, because it doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: @phant0m I meant the numbers can be as large as 10^36 and yes O() notation is not good to use but i think it conveys the message.